# Trouble visualizing the stack and heap

Tags: c, pointers

I apologize if this is too much code to post, I will delete this if that it is the case. My code below compiles and runs fine but I am unsure if I am allocating memory in the correct spots. Particularly, task 7 and 8. Task 7 should be an array of 10 pointers allocated on the
stack with each pointer referring to 10 unique instances allocated on the heap. Task 8 should be a single pointer allocated on the stack with the pointer referring to an array of 10 instances allocated on the heap. I feel like I have done task 7 and 8 backwards. As you can probably tell this is an assignment and I'm not looking for direct answers. I would just like to know if I'm on the right track for task 7 and 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10


/* Task 1 -- add typedef and rename to Point3d */

typedef struct POINT_3D
{
    int x_cord;
    int y_cord;
    int z_cord;
} Point3d;

/*Add function prototypes here*/


void init_Point1(Point3d* pt);

Point3d init_Point2(Point3d pt);

void PrintPoint1 (Point3d *pt);

void PrintPoint2(Point3d pt);


int main()
{
    int i;
    Point3d pt1;
    /* Task 2 -- using proper operator give values (5,4,2) to pt1
       and use the proper Print function to print it */
    pt1.x_cord = 5;
    pt1.y_cord = 4;
    pt1.z_cord = 2;

    printf("Printing Point3d:");
    PrintPoint1(&pt1);

    /*Task 3 -- Declare a pointer of type Point3d named ptr1*/
    Point3d  *ptr1;


    /*Task 4 -- Allocate memory for ptr1 and initialize it by
    calling init_Point1() function and use the proper Print function to print it */
    ptr1 = (Point3d*) malloc(sizeof(Point3d));
    init_Point1(ptr1);

    printf("Printing Point3d:");
    PrintPoint1(ptr1);

    //Declaring second variable pt2

    Point3d pt2;

    /*Task 5 and 6 -- Compelete init_Point2 function and
     call it with pt2 to create a point with random coordinates)
     , use the proper Print function to print it*/
    init_Point2 (pt2);


    printf("Printing Point3d:");
    PrintPoint2(pt2);

/************************************************/
/*************** Part 2 *************************/
/************************************************/
    /* All three variables p1, p2, and p3 are intended to be used as *
     * some form of array of the struct type declared above.         */

    Point3d p1[SIZE];
    Point3d* p2[SIZE];
    Point3d* p3;




    printf ("Calling init_Point1()\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf ("For position %d\n", i);
        init_Point1 (&p1[i]);
        PrintPoint1(&p1[i]);
        //PrintPoint2(p1[i])
    }


/*Task 7 -- Repeat the same steps for array p2, you must call a
   proper init function and display the results by calling Print function */

/***********************************/
/* p2 : Declare, Initialize, Print */
/***********************************/

    printf ("Calling init_Point1()\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        p2[i] = (Point3d*) malloc(sizeof(Point3d));
        printf ("For position %d\n", i);
        init_Point1 (p2[i]);
        PrintPoint1 (p2[i]);
    }





/* Task 8 -- p3 is a single pointer that must refer to an array of 10 instances
   allocated on the heap. Repeat the previous steps for p3 by initializing and
  printing using proper functions*/

/***********************************/
/* p3 : Declare, Initialize, Print */
/***********************************/

p3 = (Point3d*) malloc(sizeof(Point3d)*SIZE);


    printf ("Calling init_Point1()\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf ("For position %d\n", i);
        init_Point1 (&p3[i]);
        PrintPoint1 (&p3[i]);
    }




    return 0;
}


/************************/
/* function definitions */
/************************/


void init_Point1 (Point3d *pt)
{
    pt->x_cord = rand() % 100;
    pt->y_cord = rand() % 1000;
    pt->z_cord = rand() % 100;

}

/* Task 5 - write init_Point2() function definition */

Point3d init_Point2 (Point3d pt)
{
    pt.x_cord = rand() % 100;
    pt.y_cord = rand() % 1000;
    pt.z_cord = rand() % 100;

    return pt;
}



void PrintPoint1 (Point3d *pt)
{
    printf("\t(x %d , y %d , z  %d ) \t", pt->x_cord, pt->y_cord, pt->z_cord);
    printf("\n");

}

void PrintPoint2 (Point3d pt)
{

    printf("\t(x %d , y %d , z  %d ) \t", pt.x_cord, pt.y_cord, pt.z_cord);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Your use of stack vs heap looks correct. Generally speaking stack means a local variable and heap means dynamically allocated with `malloc` (or similar function). But for task 7 you did not do "each pointer referring to 10 unique instances allocated on the heap". `p2[i] = (Point3d*) malloc(sizeof(Point3d));` only allocates one elelement and not 10.

Comment: I agree with @kaylum except that you do task 7 as required. You have the `malloc` in the loop, which is performed 10 times, so you will indeed get 10 unique instances.

Comment: @lxop You could be right. But the question says: **each pointer**. That is, each pointer should have 10 elements.

Comment: I think you need to back up and get task 5 working first. I tried compiling your code, and there is one warning, stating that `pt2` is not initialized when passed to `init_Point2`. If you didn't see that warning, you need to turn up the warning level, e.g. use options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` with gcc or clang. To prove to yourself that the code isn't working, change the `rand()` calls in `init_Point2` to hard-coded numbers, e.g. 42, 750, and 37, and then look at what your code prints.

Comment: @kaylum interesting, that's another way to read it. However since it doesn't say each pointer points to *an array of* 10 unique instances, surely it must be the way I have interpreted it? A single pointer can't point to 10 things at once.

Comment: @lxop: I'd guess they meant "array" and just worded sloppily.

Comment: I agree there is too much code. You should concentrate the code on the things you're unsure of.